# SQL Having sum group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Syntax using Having, Group By. I need to fix the syntax. Expected output is shown in the image format.

```
 select     
            DPC.EnglishProductCategoryName,
            DP.ListPrice,
            DST.SalesTerritoryGroup
from        FactInternetSales FIS
inner join  DimProduct DP
on          FIS.ProductKey = DP.ProductKey
inner join  DimSalesTerritory DST
on          FIS.SalesTerritoryKey = DST.SalesTerritoryKey
inner join  DimProductSubcategory DPSC
on          DPSC.ProductSubcategoryKey = DP.ProductSubcategoryKey
inner join  DimProductCategory DPC
on          DPC.ProductCategoryKey = DPSC.ProductCategoryKey
where       DPC.ProductCategoryKey in (1,2,3)
Having sum(DP.ListPrice)
Group by DPC.EnglishProductCategoryName
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      DPC.EnglishProductCategoryName,
            DST.SalesTerritoryGroup,
            CAST(SUM(DP.ListPrice) AS INT) AS ListPrice_Total
from        FactInternetSales FIS
inner join  DimProduct DP
on          FIS.ProductKey = DP.ProductKey
inner join  DimSalesTerritory DST
on          FIS.SalesTerritoryKey = DST.SalesTerritoryKey
inner join  DimProductSubcategory DPSC
on          DPSC.ProductSubcategoryKey = DP.ProductSubcategoryKey
inner join  DimProductCategory DPC
on          DPC.ProductCategoryKey = DPSC.ProductCategoryKey
where       DPC.ProductCategoryKey in (1,2,3)
Group by DPC.EnglishProductCategoryName, DST.SalesTerritoryGroup
```

I converted the value to integer, just as an illustration to avoid the decimal values. You can do that directly in SSRS as well. If you are trying to pull this data just by using SSMS, then you should look into Pivoting and here is an article I wrote on Pivot. http://sqlsaga.com/sql-server/how-to-use-pivot-to-transform-rows-into-columns-in-sql-server/

It will come upto something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
select     
            DPC.EnglishProductCategoryName,
            DST.SalesTerritoryGroup,
            DP.ListPrice
from        FactInternetSales FIS
inner join  DimProduct DP
on          FIS.ProductKey = DP.ProductKey
inner join  DimSalesTerritory DST
on          FIS.SalesTerritoryKey = DST.SalesTerritoryKey
inner join  DimProductSubcategory DPSC
on          DPSC.ProductSubcategoryKey = DP.ProductSubcategoryKey
inner join  DimProductCategory DPC
on          DPC.ProductCategoryKey = DPSC.ProductCategoryKey
where       DPC.ProductCategoryKey in (1,2,3)
) a
PIVOT (SUM(ListPrice) FOR SalesTerritoryGroup IN ([North America], [Europe], [Pacific]))pvt
```

Since you are limiting the product categories, I think your expected output is not seen.

Comment: Thanks it works. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157334(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DPC.EnglishProductCategoryName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DST.SalesTerritoryGroup = 'North America' THEN DP.ListPrice ELSE 0 END as NorthAmerica,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DST.SalesTerritoryGroup = 'Europe' THEN DP.ListPrice ELSE 0 END as Europe,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DST.SalesTerritoryGroup = 'Pacific' THEN DP.ListPrice ELSE 0 END as Pacific
FROM FactInternetSales FIS
INNER JOIN DimProduct DP ON FIS.ProductKey = DP.ProductKey
INNER JOIN DimSalesTerritory DST on FIS.SalesTerritoryKey = DST.SalesTerritoryKey
INNER JOIN DimProductSubcategory DPSC  on DPSC.ProductSubcategoryKey = DP.ProductSubcategoryKey
INNER JOIN DimProductCategory DPC on DPC.ProductCategoryKey = DPSC.ProductCategoryKey
WHERE DPC.ProductCategoryKey in (1,2,3)
GROUP BY DPC.EnglishProductCategoryName, DST.SalesTerritoryGroup
```